# Изменение числа

Tags: python, функции, числа

Как сделать чтобы функция запрашивала число а потом это же число разделяла при помощи дефисов? Например: 365 = 3-6-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
number = input()
print('-'.join(number))
```

Или в одну строчку:

```
print('-'.join(input()))
```

Comment: Cпасибо огромное, работает, но еще вопрос. что здесь означает 'join'

Comment: @user402460 `join` как раз и соединяет переданный ему итерируемый объект (в данном случае строку со входа по буквам) указанным разделителем в одну строку

Answer (score 3):

Для ввода числа можно использовать функцию `input` более подробно можно ознакомиться по ссылке: https://younglinux.info/python/input.php
Для разделения числа можно использовать функцию `join`, более подробная информация https://andreyex.ru/yazyk-programmirovaniya-python/uchebnik-po-python-3/python-3-strokovaya-funkciya-join/

Все вместе выглядит примерно так:

```
x = input()

print('-'.join(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lambda i: ' '.join(j for j in str(i))
```

```
lambda i: '-'.join(j for j in str(i))
```